# How to use await to get JSON response and retry if it's returned NULL

Tags: javascript, json, search, async-await, request

My app has a search function that returns JSON.

The JSON will return NULL if it's not -quite- ready and needs a few more seconds to process.

If the JSON request is returned as NULL, I need to retry every second until it's not NULL.

Here is my JS:

```
async search(q, callback) {
  const response = await get(this.urlValue, {
    query: { q: q },
    responseKind: 'json'
  })

  if (response.ok) {
    const list = await checkIfResponseNotNull();
  }

  function checkIfResponseNotNull() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (response.json === null) {
          // Try again?
        } else {
          return callback(response.json)
        }
      }, 500)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: If you are performing await on the API call then, you will only move on if the data is returned from the API. Also considering the fact you will try each second, instead you can recurse the search function with a base condition. That will be lesser code and easy to work with

Comment: @SARANSURYA the data is returned correctly, but it returns as NULL (API needs between 2-30 seconds to process data and images) – hoping for it to loop if it's returned as NULL until it's no longer returned as NULL.

Comment: Are you using the fetch API ? Can you share the source of the get() function. I am still not able to find references of it in MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=get

Comment: I am not sure if trying every second is a good idea. Because you will try 30 times until you have a non-null result and in my opinion it makes the await pointless. Do you know why API call returns null if it is not ready? Idea behind await to wait for an answer and ideally Api shouldn't give you null until it has an actual response. In the worst case it should give a timeout error and you can set your timeout period when you make the request. I understand your need to repeat the requests but I am not sure if it would solve your problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively call the `search` method when `response`, or `response.json`, is null.

```
const search = async (q, callback) => {
  console.log("searching for: " + q);
  try {
    const response = await get();

    console.log(response);
    if (response?.json) {
      console.log("response found");
      return callback(response.json);
    }

    console.log("retry search");
    await search(q, callback);
  } catch {
    // await search(q, callback) // Also try again when request fauls?
  }
};
```

A simple example can be found here: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-snowflake-bswt6i?file=/src/index.js:254-666)